# Create and show thumbnail (byte[]) in JSF

Tags: jsf, thumbnails, tomahawk

I'm uploading image to server and when image is uploaded it should show me a thumb of uploaded image. Thumbnail is not saved on hard disc I use InputStream and OutputStream. For upload i'm ustig tomahawk.

my index.jsp:

```xml
<h:form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <t:inputFileUpload id="fileupload" 
    accept="image/*" 
    storage="file"
    value="#{fileUpload.uploadedFile}" 
    styleClass="fileUploadInput"
    required="true" 
    validator="epacient.FileUploadValidator"
    requiredMessage="Obvezna izbira datoteke." 
  />
  <br />
  <h:message for="fileupload" infoStyle="color: green;"
    errorStyle="color: red;" />
  <br />
  <h:commandButton value="Upload" id="fileUploadButton"
    action="#{fileUpload.upload}" />
  <h:message for="uploadForm" style="color: red;" />
  <h:graphicImage value="#{fileUpload.thumb}"
    rendered="#{fileUpload.uploaded}" />

</h:form>
```

fileUpload.upload calls function `String preview()`

```java
private  String thumb ;
public String preview() throws IOException{
  HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext
    .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
  try {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map requestMap = context.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap();
    byte[] bytes = (byte[])(requestMap.get("fileupload_bytes")); 
    // returns byte[]
    byte[] testByte = createThumbnail(bytes, 200);
    // here thumbnail is created
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

createThumbnail:

```java
public static byte[] createThumbnail( byte[] orig, int maxDim) {
  try {
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(orig);
    Image inImage = imageIcon.getImage();
    double scale = (double) maxDim / (double) inImage.getWidth(null);

    int scaledW = (int) (scale * inImage.getWidth(null));
    int scaledH = (int) (scale * inImage.getHeight(null));

    BufferedImage outImage = new BufferedImage(scaledW, scaledH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();

    if (scale < 1.0d) {
      tx.scale(scale, scale);
    }

    Graphics2D g2d = outImage.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(inImage, tx, null);
    g2d.dispose();  

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(outImage, "JPG", baos);
    byte[] bytesOut = baos.toByteArray();

    return bytesOut;
  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
}
```

Now I have my thumbnail but it is in `byte[]` can any body tell me how to show my thumb with `<h:graphicImage>` tag? Or any other way.

Thank you !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The images counts each as a **separate request**. You *cannot* process *both* the HTML response (of JSF) and the image in a single request/response cycle. You need to store the image/thumb somewhere in a datastore which lives longer than a request, e.g. the server's local disk file system (temp folder? webcontent folder?), or a database (temp table?), or in the session.

First, replace

```
<h:graphicImage value="#{fileUpload.thumb}" ...
```

by

```
<h:graphicImage value="thumbs/#{fileUpload.thumbId}" ...
```

so that it get generated as

```
<img src="thumbs/123" ...
```

(the `src` should namely point to a **valid URL**)

Then, create a `HttpServlet` which is mapped on an `url-pattern` of `/thumbs/*` and implement `doGet()` roughly like follows:

```
Long thumbId = Long.valueOf(request.getPathInfo().substring(1)); // 123
byte[] thumb = getItFromDiskOrDatabaseOrSessionByThumbId(thumbId);
String filename = getOriginalFilenameOfUploadedImageOrInventOne();

response.setContentType(getServletContext().getMimeType(filename));
response.setContentLength(thumb.length);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

BufferedInputStream input = null;
BufferedOutputStream output = null;

try {
    input = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(thumb));
    output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
} finally {
    if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
}
```

That's it. More servlet hints can be found in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html).

Answer (score 3):

The `graphicImage` tag generates an `img` tag in the HTML response. So you need to provide the URL of an image in the `value` attribute of the `graphicImage` tag, which will correspond to the `src` attribute of the `img` tag.

You can either:

- Write the thumbnail on the `filesystem` in a path that is accessible form the outside through HTTP. You can then reference the image directly in the `value` attribute in the `graphicImage`, e.g. `/myapp/thumbnail/12345`.
- Write a `servlet` that serves the image when requested. The servlet can either read the image from memory (`HttpSession`), the filesystem, or a database, or generate it each time. In this case you need to pass a parameter to the servlet, e.g. `/myapp/thumbnail.do?filename=12345`

In short, you will need to store your `byte[]` thumbnail somewhere (session, filesystem, database), to be able to serve it as regular resource, either directly or through a servlet.

Answer (score 1):

Richfaces has abstracted this for you. Check [`<a4j:mediaOutput>`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/mediaOutput.jsf?c=mediaOutput&tab=usage) - you just write your `byte[]` to an `OutputStream` provided by the component.

Comment: The a4j:mediaOutput contains constraint on image size because it encodes image content into URL (base64 form). It's applicable only for small icons only

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ewernli.  I've reused your createThumbnail util method.  I added this little enhancement so that the original image is returned if its width is less than the stipulated maxDim width.  I did this because I ran into a situation where the method returned an image that was bigger than the original, padded with black pixels.

```
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(orig);
        Image inImage = imageIcon.getImage();

        int origWidth = inImage.getWidth(null);
        if(origWidth < maxDim) {
            return orig;
        }

        ...
```