# How to convert BufferedImage to image to display on JSP

Tags: image, jsp, bufferedimage

I would like to convert `BufferedImage` to an image that will display on JSP page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The parent class of `BuferedImage` is `Image`. Can you be more specific?

Comment: yes, please more information needed. Where do you have this image? One of possible ways is just use Servlet, which will write BufferedImage to response, and on JSP page you write a link to this servlet. Just shortly, sounds good but I'm not sure that it covers your case...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, JSP is a view technology providing a template to write HTML/CSS/JS in and the ability to interact with backend Java code to control page flow and access backend data. Your problem is more in HTML.

Now, to display an image in a HTML page, you need the HTML `<img>` element. To define/allocate an image, you just have to let the `src` attribute point to an URL. E.g.

```
<img src="url/to/image.jpg" />
```

(it can be either relative to the current context, or an absolute URL, e.g. starting with `http://`)

If the image is dynamic, as in your case, you need to have a `Servlet` which listens on the `url-pattern` matching the image URL. E.g.

```
<img src="imageservlet/image.jpg" />
```

(here the servlet is obviously to be mapped on an URL pattern of `/imageservlet/*` and the image identifier, here the filename, is here available by `request.getPathInfo()`)

The `<img src>` will fire a GET request, so you just have to implement `doGet()` method of the servlet. To send a HTTP response all you need to do is to write some content to the `OutputStream` of the response, along with a set of response headers representing the content (`Content-Type`, `Content-Length` and/or `Content-disposition`). You can use [`ImageIO#write()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write-java.awt.image.RenderedImage-java.lang.String-java.io.OutputStream-) to write a `BufferedImage` to an `OutputStream`.

You can find a basic example of such an image servlet [here](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2007/04/imageservlet.html). You just have to replace `Files#copy()` with [`ImageIO#write()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write-java.awt.image.RenderedImage-java.lang.String-java.io.OutputStream-).

```
response.setContentType("image/png");
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", response.getOutputStream());
```

---

As a completely different alternative, you can also let the servlet convert the image to a Base64 encoded string and pass it on to the JSP:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", output);
String imageAsBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(output.toByteArray());
request.setAttribute("imageAsBase64", imageAsBase64);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/some.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And finally show it in the forwarded JSP using the [data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) as below:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,${imageAsBase64}" />
```

You only need to keep in mind that this doesn't give the server nor the client the opportunity to cache the image. So this approach is plain inefficient in case the image is not temporary.

---

#### See also:

- [How to retrieve and display images from a database in a JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/how-to-retrieve-and-display-images-from-a-database-in-a-jsp-page/)
- [Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java)

Answer (score 6):

You need not convert  `BufferedImage` to `Image` to display it on the *jsp* page. Because, Java 6 JAXB provides `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(byte[]) String` to convert *byte[]* in to *base 64 string*. The *base 64 string* can be displayed using the `<img` *html* tag by specifying the source data as `base 64` i.e. `src="data:image/jpg`;. Here is the sample program referred from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878562/unable-to-display-all-info-from-the-database-through-jsp/22879097#22879097).

*sample.jsp* (test passed) :

```
<%@page import="java.awt.image.BufferedImage"%>
<%@page import="javax.imageio.ImageIO"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/visruth/Desktop/Visruth.jpg"));//give the path of an image
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write( bImage, "jpg", baos );
baos.flush();
byte[] imageInByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
String b64 = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageInByteArray);
%>

<div>
    <p>As of v6, Java SE provides JAXB</p>
    <img src="data:image/jpg;base64, <%=b64%>" alt="Visruth.jpg not found" />
</div>          
</body>
</html>
```

IMO, this approach is perfect for small sized images like `<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="200" alt="thumbnail" height="200">`. Otherwise using direct url of the image will be fine in `src` attribute eg:- `<img src="uri-of-image/profile-pic.jpg" width="600" alt="No Profie Pic" height="600">`

Comment: @Md.NaushadAlam It's my pleasure!

Comment: On this line `ImageIO.write( bImage, "jpg", baos );` you anyway convert bufferedimage to image.

Comment: It's writing `jpg` image bytes to `baos` array.

Comment: `Image` is another class in Java that's why I said "*You need not convert  `BufferedImage` to `Image`*"