# How to display a buffered image in a jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, bufferedimage

Hai guys,
I have a java page and there is a buffered image in it. I want to pass this buffered image into a jsp page and i want to display it there. Guys so pls help me to do it. I am new in java. so help me with simple codes.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert BufferedImage to Image to display on JSP.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438375/how-to-convert-bufferedimage-to-image-to-display-on-jsp)

Answer (score 2):

1. you can write buffered image to some public web space and provide src to that in img tag
2. provide src as servlet and output the image directly from the servlet

**Also See**

- [how-to-convert-bufferedimage-to-image-to-display-on-jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438375/how-to-convert-bufferedimage-to-image-to-display-on-jsp)
- [Example from BalusC blog](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample program taken [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878562/unable-to-display-all-info-from-the-database-through-jsp/22879097#22879097). It works fine.

```
<%@page import="java.awt.image.BufferedImage"%>
<%@page import="javax.imageio.ImageIO"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/visruth/Desktop/Visruth.jpg"));//give the path of an image
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write( bImage, "jpg", baos );
baos.flush();
byte[] imageInByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
String b64 = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageInByteArray);
%>

<div>
    <p>As of v6, Java SE provides JAXB</p>
    <img src="data:image/jpg;base64, <%=b64%>" alt="Visruth.jpg not found" />
</div>          
</body>
</html>
```