# unable to display all info from the database through jsp

Tags: java, jsp

My requirement is to insert artist details and his picture through jsp into oracle database and retrieve back information and picture through another jsp program.

artist table has five columns, four are varchar2 and fifth column is blob type.

I have successfully inserted and successfully able to retrieve but the problem it displays only image. Below is the code. I am stuck. I need help. Please suggest me.

```
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from artist");
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){ %>
            <table><tr><th>artist fast name:</th><td><%=rs.getString(1) %></td></tr> 
                <tr><th>artist middle name:</th><td><%=rs.getString(2) %></td></tr>
                <tr><th>artist last name</th><td><%=rs.getString(3) %></td></tr>
                <tr><th>artist job</th><td><%=rs.getString(4) %></td></tr>
                <tr><th>artist image</th><td><img src="
            <%
                Blob bl=rs.getBlob(5);
                byte[] image=bl.getBytes(1, (int)bl.length());
                response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
                OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
                o.write(image);
                o.flush();
                o.close();
         }
            %>" height="100" width="100" alt="bye"/> </td></tr>
            </table> 
                <%
           con.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 6, Java SE provides JAXB by which the *bytes* may be converted in to *base64 string*. Here also you may convert the image `byte[]` into *base 64 string* and it can be displayed using the `<img` *html* tag specifying the src data as base 64 i.e. `src="data:image/png;base64,`.

Modify your code as follows :

```
<%
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from artist");
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){ %>
            <table><tr><th>artist fast name:</th><td><%=rs.getString(1) %></td></tr> 
                <tr><th>artist middle name:</th><td><%=rs.getString(2) %></td></tr>
                <tr><th>artist last name</th><td><%=rs.getString(3) %></td></tr>
                <tr><th>artist job</th><td><%=rs.getString(4) %></td></tr>
                <tr><th>artist image</th><td>
                <%
                Blob bl=rs.getBlob(5);
                byte[] image=bl.getBytes(1, (int)bl.length());
                %>
                <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <%=javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(image)%>
            " height="100" width="100" alt="bye"/> </td></tr>
            </table> 
                <%
                }
                con.close();
          %>
```

Here is another sample *jsp* page for getting a clear idea :

```
<%@page import="java.awt.image.BufferedImage"%>
<%@page import="javax.imageio.ImageIO"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/visruth/Desktop/Visruth.jpg"));//give the path of an image
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write( bImage, "jpg", baos );
baos.flush();
byte[] imageInByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
String b64 = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageInByteArray);
%>

<div>
    <p>As of v6, Java SE provides JAXB</p>
    <img src="data:image/jpg;base64, <%=b64%>" alt="Visruth.jpg not found" />
</div>          
</body>
</html>
```