# Show Multiple BufferedImage in jsp

Tags: java, image, jsp, bufferedimage

I have 100 `BufferedImage` object's in `ArrayList`, i want to show all of these images in a jsp.

```
<%
  ArrayList<BufferedImage> list = GlobalData.getImageBufferArrayList();
%>

 </head>
 <body>
 <ul>
 <li><img alt="" src=""> </li>//image1
 <li><img alt="" src=""> </li>//image2
 <li><img alt="" src=""> </li>//image3
   ...
   ..
   ...
 </ul>
</body>
```

I don't know what to put in `src` on these images

Is it possible to put image data as `src` of image.(Just like we get image data from `canvas` in html)

Or is their any decent way of showing these images.

Comment: you can save the images names/paths on string array and then in a "for" loop just write <li><img alt = "" src=arr[i].toString()></li>

Comment: i don't have images on disk

Comment: you need a separate servlet that has a header content type image/png or jpg or gif. this servlet gets a buffered image and outputs it. in each src attributes let 

    src='servlet?img=NUMBER'

where NUMBER is the index of each image in the arraylist.

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438375/how-to-convert-bufferedimage-to-image-to-display-on-jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to embed the image files into the HTML document, or make it available through separate HTTP requests. For the former you can use the [`data:` URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). For the latter, you have to provide a separate servlet, or a separate code path inside that same servlet, which will serve the image file. It might do so from some short-lived cache, so you won't have to execute the same code again to obtain these images.

In general, embedding the data has a size overhead proportional to the size of the image, whereas the separate requests have a resource overhead proportional to the number of HTTP requests. For small images, the former might be better, while for large images the latter will be faster. Implementing the embedding should be easier than implementing a reasonable image cache, but I'm not 100% sure whether all browser support the data scheme.

In either case, you'll have to serialize the [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) to some byte sequence first, probably using [`ImageIO.write`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) in conjunction with a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).