# how to print image in jsp using bufferedimage

Tags: jsp

I having image byte array in app_be.getBytes().

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(app_be.getBytes()));
```

i having this line in my jsp.I got image in img.how can i display this image in my jsp img tag can u help me.
other than this image all working properly.
Like this i want to print tat img can u please help me

```
<img src="<%= img%>" height="100%" width="100%" >
```

i tried like this `<img src="<%= img.getSource()%>" height="100%" width="100%" >`
but tat also not working i dont know how to display img plz help me.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438375/how-to-convert-bufferedimage-to-image-to-display-on-jsp

Comment: ashokdamani s i already tried tat way its working.in servlet.i took tat byte array in jsp i want to process here and want to display plz help for tat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code inside your servlet

```
BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(new File("filepath");
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", byteArrayOS);
byte [] byteArray=byteArrayOS.toByteArray();
photo="data:image/jpg;base64,"+Base64.encode(byteArray);
```

print the value of photo in your jsp as

```
<img height="100px" src="${photo}" alt="Photo" />
```

This worked for me . have a glance over this