# Converting a Blob to an image

Tags: jsp, blob

I have stored an image in a database using Blob type. Now I can fetch this image from database using the select. I want to display this image on my jsp. In Jsp i have created a table and want it to be one of the column.

I have blob data how can I convert it back to an image and display it on my jsp page.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve and display images from a database in a JSP page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/how-to-retrieve-and-display-images-from-a-database-in-a-jsp-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two options:

Option 1:

This may not be the best answer, but it will do in a pinch...

You would need to use a `InputStreamReader` to read the blob out of the column, and then create a `FileOutputStream` and then create the file in a 'created' images directory. For example if you store you image files in a directory called `/pics`, you could write the files out to a directory called `/pics/generated`.

There are some drawbacks to this approach. For one you would generate a file every time the page is requested. which may work if the files will all have different names.

Option 2:

You would use an InputStreamReader to read the blob from the row that is returned from your SQL. Create an OutputStream, using a `byte[]` as the stream destination. Then it's just a matter of writing the `byte[]` out to your JSP

Comment: Thanks after 4 hours I am finally done. The problem was not in creating the File from byte[] but was wit displaying it on screen. Coz if I save it on my C:\ i am nt able to use it so had too get context path and all i.e. used this "this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/Soccer")" and this stored the generated image in the web folder. Now I could access these generated pic.... phew.....

Comment: @Ace Great job, I'll keep that in mind the next time I have to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just obtain an `InputStream` of the blob using [`ResultSet#getBinaryStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream%28int%29) and write it immediately to the `OutputStream` of the HTTP response along a correct set of headers. There's absolutely no need to store it temporarily on disk as suggested in other answer.

More detail and complete code example can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/retrieve-multiple-images-from-mysql/2341322#2341322).