# When saving an image as BLOB how to display it in JSP with text?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, image-processing, spring-mvc

I have done a lot of googling but I have not been able to find a concrete answer.

I am using Spring MVC 3 to save a user image to the database. I am now successfully able to do that. I am saving the image as a `BLOB`.

I can retrieve the image as a `byte[]`.

Irregardless of file type - jpg, png, gif etc (My image upload is image file type agnostic) I would like to allow jpg and gif and png lets say to render i.e. my display technology should not be hard-coded to display just one type of image, say jpg, it should be able to display all images as they were uploaded in their respective types - that is the requirement.

NOW, I would like to do 2 things

1. re-size the image if I have to. ie.
   200 by 200
2. render the image in a JSP WITH text.
   This is a user profile page so I
   need to have both text and image
   shown.

**How can spring mvc render the image WITH text?**

I understand from my research that you can use a `BufferedImage` type for the jsp? but my problem is that it seems that you can only use that if the content type is strictly `image/jpeg`, `image/gif`.

I have come across some links for resizing:
http://forum.springsource.org/archiv...p/t-46021.html

any suggestions welcome if these work BUT ultimately I need to display the image.

Please pass your thoughts along.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a servlet which streams the image from the DB to the outputstream of the response. Then you can just call it the usual HTML way as follows:

```
<p>
   <img src="imageservlet/${bean.imageId}" />
   ${bean.text}
</p>
```

As you see, you just display the text next to the image in HTML. You cannot mix them in a single HTTP response anyway. Images counts as separate HTTP requests. For more detail and a kickoff code example of such a servlet, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/retrieve-multiple-images-from-mysql/2341322#2341322).

As to resizing, checkout the Java 2D API.