# Spring: how to show image with other content on JSP page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When saving an image as BLOB how to display it in JSP with text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775201/when-saving-an-image-as-blob-how-to-display-it-in-jsp-with-text)
>   [Spring - display image on jsp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066349/spring-display-image-on-jsp-file)

I want to show image gallery on my web page with some content below it. But I can't figure out how to pass my image from database to my page such as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("serverTime", /*my image as byte[] ?!*/);
    return "home";
}
```

I have found some example that tells that I can't show the image and content are mapped on the same url pattern. If it is true, could you please give me an example how to do it?

Comment: is your image stored in a DB?

Comment: Yes, images are stored in db (MySql)