# Want to display binary images on jsp

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am stored an image in postgres sql as bytea[] field.That is in byte format.I want to view the perfect image into my jsp page after storing the image.Please, point me to the solution or some ways to achieve this requirement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243726/how-to-display-an-image-in-jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covert your image to `Base64`:

```
String imageBase64 = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(imageByteArray))
```

Note that `Base64` class is coming from `java.util` package. If you not using JDK 8 you can easily find an alternative to do that.

Then in your JSP page:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,${imageBase64}" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I tried the code.But problem is the same.

Comment: This is the right way to do it. Please amend your question with the details of what exactly is not working.

Comment: Thank you sir for the reply...I got the answer.Only one change is there to view the image.<img src="data:image/png;base64,<%=imageBase64%>" >