# Display image in jsp page from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

My code is uploading an image and saving the image to my server, but I need to display the image in my jsp page.

The jsp for uploading image

**uploadImage.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head><title>Image Upload</title></head>

<body>
  <form action="UploadImage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
           name="productForm" id="productForm"><br><br>
    <table width="400px" align="center" border=0 style="background-color:ffeeff;">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan=2 style="font-weight:bold;font-size:20pt;">
           Image Details</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Image Link: </td>
        <td>
          <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;

        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Servlet

UploadImage

```
public class UploadImage extends HttpServlet {
    /**
     * 
     */

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2082405235440894340L;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        File filenameImg;
        List<FileItem> items = null;
        try {
            items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory())
                    .parseRequest(request);
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Cannot parse multipart request.", e);
        }

        for (FileItem item : items) {
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                // Process regular form fields here the same way as
                // request.getParameter().
                // You can get parameter name by
                item.getFieldName();
                // You can get parameter value by item.getString();
            } else {

                try{
                    // Process uploaded fields here.
                    String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
                    // Get filename.
                    String path = GetWebApplicationPathServlet.getContext().getRealPath("/images");

                    File file =  new File(path,filename);


                    //File file = new File("C:\\", filename);

                    // Define destination file.

                    item.write(file);
                    System.out.println("filename: "+filename);
                    System.out.println("file: "+file);
                    request.setAttribute("image", file);
                    filenameImg = file;
                    // Write to destination file.
                //  request.setAttribute("image", filename);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
        // Show result page.


        System.out.println("request"+request.getAttribute("image"));
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg"); 
        //request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp").forward(request, response);

        String nextJSP = "/result.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

result.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%=request.getParameter("image")%>

<img src="<%=request.getParameter("image")%>">
</body>
</html>
```

***<%=request.getParameter("image")%>
 is returned as null in the result.jsp page***

Help

Comment: Can you tell us whether you're willing to store this image at some location before preview? .. will be helpful pls answer

Comment: @Falcon  i need to store the image in my tomcar server. i have craeted a folder images in my project and the image is being saved in that particular directory, but my problem is that im not able to show that saved image in my jsp page

Comment: You are doing it right. Now just pass path in request with name of the uploaded image.

Comment: check my answer, point 1 may be helpful in this case

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/retrieve-multiple-images-from-mysql/2341322#2341322

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm considering you are storing a image file somewhere on the server -

1. If that path is inside your application then you can give that path directly in the image src attribute, e.g. -  
   if you're storing file somewhere like `<context root>/resources/image/someImage.jpg` then you can give that path (path should be inside the application which is accessible via browser with your context rrot) image src attribute and browser will point to that image.
2. You can store the file somewhere in the server (outside of the application say "d:\someImage.jpg") then this cannot be reachable by the browser directly but you can still show that image via servlet, e.g. - 
   you can write a new servlet and in the goGet method you can read the image file and write it to the response output stream. give this servlet url in the src of the image like -

e.g.

```
<image src="context root/displayServlet?image=someImage.jpg">
```

The servlet code may look like -
**EDIT:** - For better code refer [How to retrieve and display images from a database in a JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/retrieve-multiple-images-from-mysql/2341322#2341322)

```
try{
         String fileName = request.getParameter("image");             
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("d:\\"+fileName));
         BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);             
         response.setContentType(contentType);
         BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
         for (int data; (data = bis.read()) > -1;) {
           output.write(data);
         }             
      }
      catch(IOException e){

      }finally{
          // close the streams
      }
```

You can improve this code, I'm just giving an example.

Comment: `InputStream#available()` does not return the file content length. It may even return `0`.

Comment: @BalusC - thanks for pointing that out.. any better alternative to that?

Comment: Just write in a loop through a buffer the usual way. You don't want to risk out of memory errors when the file content is larger than available Java memory.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem, your answer helped so much.

Answer (score 2):

`<img src="<%=request.getParameter("image")%>">`

First of all `src` of `img` tag only takes image path as string so you can not pass whole image in it.

**Now what you can do is:--** When you are uploading image on server don't save/pass whole image file in request instead only add the path of image in request where you upload image. In your code path is `path + *file separator* + filename`. Pass this to src of img tag and it will do the trick. Here *file separator* can be `"/"` or `"\\"`.

Hope this helps.

---

As suggested by [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) in comment It's better to use `<img src="${param.image}" />`.

Comment: You are wrong about the second thing. HTML and JSP scriptlet does not run in sync or something.

Comment: @BalusC: so you mean to say it will not give any error if we write like this: `<img src="<%=request.getParameter("image")%>">`

Comment: Correct. Maybe buggy editors do (either by warnings or suggestive highlighting), but it's technically perfectly fine. Try it yourself. You're probably confusing with mixing HTML with JavaScript. Since they runs both at client machine, quoting matters.

Comment: @BalusC: you are right. Thnx. let me update my answer.

Comment: It is **not better** to use it that way. Using `<img src="${param.image}" />` is way much better.

Comment: I did not mean to imply that this is *the* answer. It's just the style.

Comment: @BalusC: If its better option than it must be in answer as a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes to the approach you have taken. First, in the above servlet code you have coded as if you are downloading an image file (You have set the content type as image.

Second, you have in no way associated the image file to response. Not through a image parameter or through a stream.

Now, since you have mixed up two approaches.. you need to decide what you need first. From your explanation, I understand that you are trying to display the uploaded image in the result.jpg. In that case, you don't need to send the image with content type set. In your result.jsp, the img tag expects the path of the image to be displayed. So, you need to set the path of your image to "image" attribute in response.

```
response.setAttribute("image", imagepath);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

the image path should be some valid URL to access the image.In your result.jsp you need:

```
request.getParameter("image");
```

to get the image. Here is how it will be:

```
<img src='<%=request.getParameter("image")%>'>
```

Comment: i have done as u suggested and the image is being displayed in my eclipse browser. But when i took the application in my IE, the image is not shown there...Pls hep

Answer (score 0):

In Your servlet set a request attribute which returns full path of your image to JSP.

```
String fullpath = path + File.separator + filename

request.setAttribute("fullpath",fullpath);
```

You are already forwarding request to JSP.

So, now get the attribute using

```
<% 

String path = "";
if(request.getAttribute("fullpath")!=null)
    path = request.getAttribute("fullpath").toString();

%>
```

in your JSP and then display the image using that path

```
<img src='<%=path%>'>
```

Comment: What do you mean by full path? if the image is stored on 'd' drive then full path would be 'd:\someImage.jpg'.. is that what you mean? if so then it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Jeje, the problem of null is because are diferent things; Attributes and Parameters, if you did:

```
request.setAttribute("image", file.getPath());
```

then you need to do:

```
request.getAttribute("image")
```