# How to uploading an image showing it on the same page?

Tags: java, image, jsp

I am working on a JSP project where the user needs to upload an image.
I need this image to be stored into the database so that it can be retrieved from the database later on. I need to show that image in the webpage itself as soon as the image has been loaded. I have tried several option like [uploadbean](http://www.javazoom.net/jzservlets/uploadbean/documentation/software.html), [spring-3-mvc-fileupload-example.html](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/web/spring-3-mvc-fileupload-example.html), etc but nothing is working out for me.

Can you please give me a simple but effective way to do this? I am working with MySQL database.

Comment: Are you using Spring MVC or not? Your Roseindia.net (*shudder*) link assumes that you're using Spring MVC. Do you expect an answer targeted on Spring MVC framework or just "plain vanilla" JSP/Servlet? For the remnant I can only say [What is it with Roseindia?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/06/what-is-it-with-roseindia.html) For plain vanilla JSP/Servlet it's however pretty simple: [How to upload files in JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2424824) and [Retrieve images from MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2341322)

Comment: I am not using Spring MVC. Thats why that code could not work. Any suggestions for the Plain Vanilla?

Comment: Thanks BacusC. The link is fantastic.Il look over to it and respond here accordingly..

Comment: *"Can you please give me a simple but effective way to do this?"* Hire someone that already knows how to do it (potentially expensive, but definitely simple).

Answer (score 1):

Apurv I suggest you look at this library

http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/

The user guide is at http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html

Comment: Thanx but iv tried this..:(..Couldnt go through this.. can u please provide me with a working example of this..???

Comment: I have some old code somewhere, if I can find it I'll post it.

Comment: What couldn't you go through, can you post your code that you tried. I've made it work before so it definitely works, but yes there are some things that are not obvious for beginners.

Comment: Sure ankur, I am trying to let the users upload there image and want to show that image as soon as the image is uploaded..

Comment: Ok, I'll try and give you a code sample. One idea is to save your image to the file server within Apache and then access it like you would any normal image.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/. It is simple and works fine. Although Spring also has wrapper for this component and I used it either directly or via Spring and both worked fine for me.