# Rendering images as a slideshow which are stored in the database as longblob

Tags: jsp, jstl

We have developed a small web application using spring and hibernate.Our application has a functionality of uplodaing the images and videos and we are storing the images and videos in the database in longblob format.
We are trying to display these images as a slideshow using an already existing javascript based "Simple Controls Gallery" http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/simplegallery.htm which is found on the internet.

I have tried to call a html page which will be redirected to a jsp page by the controller as follows :

```
var Imagearray1 = [
            <c:set var="count" value="0"/> 
            <c:set var="comma" value=","/>
            <c:forEach items="${imageList}" var="image" varStatus="loop">
            <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}"/>
              [$.get('imagedisplay.html');,'http://','${image.imageTitle}','${image.imageDescription}']<c:if test="${fn:length(imageList) != count}"> <c:out value="${comma}"/> </c:if>            
            </c:forEach>
        ];
```

where imageList is the list of images from the database. You can see the actual code of Imagearray1 in the link that i mentioned.

How can i display the images using this gallery ?(or) if there is any other way of displaying images as a slidehow please explain it to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a servlet which streams the image content from the DB to the HTTP response, along a set of proper response headers. The nonsensicial `$.get('imagedisplay.html');` ajax call must be replaced by an URL to the servlet which returns the image, e.g.

```
var images = [
    <c:forEach items="${images}" var="image" varStatus="loop">
        ['imageservlet/${image.id}', '', '${image.imageTitle}', '${image.imageDescription}']${!loop.last ? ',' : ''}
    </c:forEach>
];
```

Map your image servlet on an URL pattern of `/imageservlet/*` and get the image ID (or filename) by `request.getPathInfo()` and finally select it as `InputStream` from the DB and write it to `OutputStream` of the response. You can find a basic example in this answer: [How to retrieve and display images from a database in a JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/retrieve-multiple-images-from-mysql/2341322#2341322).