# Image is not displayed on retrieval

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a table with images stored in it as BLOB. I'm using JPA/Hibernate. Images are mapped to a bean field with type blob. Now my Spring controller is returning entire **list of bean** (each object of this bean has a blob object) to my jsp. I want to display all the images on that jsp.

I tried to use some thing like this on my jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${itemList}" var="item" varStatus="status" >

<img src="<c:out value="${item.image}" />"/><br/> /*<img src="${item.image}"/> */

</c:forEach>
```

but that is not working. Instead of getting the list of images displayed on jsp , I 'm getting the class name, when I view the page source I saw something like this `<img src="java.object.serilizableBlob@2134"/>`

Please help me delve with the problem. How can I display all the images on same jsp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<img src>` has to point to an URL, not to a `toString()` representation of some blob object. The webbrowser wouldn't understand how to download it and it will effectively end up in a HTTP 404 error.

You rather want to end up with for example this:

```html
<img src="url/to/image.png" />
```

To serve images dynamically from a database, use a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). You should then instead of a list of blobs have a list of unique image IDs/filenames so that your HTML end up like this

```html
<img src="imageservlet/image1.png" />
<img src="imageservlet/image2.png" />
<img src="imageservlet/image3.png" />
```

This way the browser can download the images by URL and display them accordingly.

No, printing binary data among all that HTML won't help. The [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) comes close, but this isn't fully supported in all modern browsers.

#### See also:

- [How to retrieve and display images from a database in a JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/how-to-retrieve-and-display-images-from-a-database-in-a-jsp-page) - this shows the "raw JDBC" example, but the idea is the same for JPA/Hibernate; just get a `byte[]` or an `InputStream` of the DB somehow and write it to the `OutputStream` of the response after having set the necessary response headers so that the browser understands how to deal with it.

Comment: I would only add that if you are using spring you should use a Controller and not implement this as a Servlet.