# i want to retrieve images from imagepaths stored in db in jsp

Tags: jsp, ms-access, jdbc

i am using jsp file and i want to retrieve images

the problem is that i have stored the image paths and i want to retrieve images to jsp page  from that image paths

how can be it possible?
I am using ms-access database.

```
Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rst = null;
    Statement st = null;

    try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:register");
            st=con.createStatement();
            rst = st.executeQuery("select * from productregistration");
                while(rst.next())
                {
                    %>
               <img src="<%=rst.getString(1)%>"/>
                    <%

                }
               }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve and display images from a database in a JSP page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/how-to-retrieve-and-display-images-from-a-database-in-a-jsp-page)

Comment: what are you trying to do with that code? the connection is not opened. `select *` is a bad thing to do. `getString(1)` is a bad thing to do. you have to add the image path to the `img` tag.

Comment: but when i write only rst.getString() , all the image paths stored in database are retrieved but when i put these values in src , i get nothing

Comment: ohkk i got my answer...it was actually relative path that i have stores instead i will store only image name and then getting it.....its called actual path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya related path cant be get instead use the absolute path