# Specify InputStream instead of resource file in PushBuilder of HTTP/2 server push

Tags: servlets, push, http2

Is there an implementation or a way to specify `InputStream` instead of just a path to a resource when pushing using Servlet 4.0 PushBuilder? I need to push chunks of data and so far I have not found a way to push the data without creating a resource file first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another servlet which writes the desired `InputStream` to the response, if necessary depending on some query or path parameter, and specify its URL in the resource list.

Comment: Example of how such a servlet would look like: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10564594

Comment: I understand what you mean - but I still have to figure out how to implement this so that the "data resource" would be called just once not multiple times. I'm looking to sending just data - and these data need to be chunked after they are retrieved. I'm not looking at exactly replacing multiple "offset-limit" calls but rather one request multiple responses.