# display blob image in jsp (javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Column '2' not found.)

Tags: mysql, image, jsp, blob

I am trying to display a blob image in a jsp page by **([using this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192020/display-blob-image-through-jsp))** but i am getting an error:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Column '2' not found.`

My table is:

```
create table upload_image
(
    iImageID int AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    bImage longblob
);
```

Code: *uploadimage.jsp*

```
<%@ page language="java"  errorPage="" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Image insert into database</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="frm" action="saveImage.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="uProperty" /> <br>
<input type="submit" name="goUpload" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

*saveImage.jsp*

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.output.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%
 Connection conn=null;
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/online","root", "12345");

 PreparedStatement psImageInsertDatabase=null;

 byte[] b=null;
 try{
   String sqlImageInsertDatabase="insert into upload_image (bImage) values(?)";
   psImageInsertDatabase=conn.prepareStatement(sqlImageInsertDatabase);

   DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

   ServletFileUpload sfu = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
   List items = sfu.parseRequest(request);

   Iterator iter = items.iterator();

     while (iter.hasNext()) {
     FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
     if (!item.isFormField()) {
          b = item.get();
       }
     }

     psImageInsertDatabase.setBytes(1,b);
     psImageInsertDatabase.executeUpdate();
    }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    e.printStackTrace();
    response.sendRedirect("addimage.jsp");
   }

   %>
```

*get.jsp*

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/online","root", "12345");
Statement st = con.createStatement();

ResultSet i = st.executeQuery("select * from upload_image");
%>

 <%

 while(i.next( )){
   %>
       <img src="imageServlet?id=<%=i.getString("2")%>" />
<%  }%>
```

After executing the *get.jsp* (after executing *uploadimage.jsp*) I am getting `"Column '2' not found."` Please help me to display the image in the jsp page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its throwing an error cause it is finding a column named as `2` since you have put 2 in double quotes.Also I feel it should be 1 and not 2(but you know better)
This is the answer below

```
 <img src="imageServlet?id=<%=i.getString(1)%>" />//with no quotes as you can see
```

or

`<img src="imageServlet?id=<%=i.getString("iImageID")%>" />`

Comment: Hi Sonny thank you for ans. After removing the quotes, i am getting output like http://imageshack.com/a/img841/5457/iyz9.png

Comment: but wat have u put?2 or 1?

Comment: wat have u put 2 or 1?

Comment: Thank you for your care......As you said i modified, but i am not able to display the image and getting error http://imageshack.com/a/img819/4482/nc16.png

Comment: @kiranlanke could u add the servlet code in your question?

Comment: @kiranlanke hope u have added your servlet to the web.xml

Comment: I don't know about servlet code, i got "imageServlet" from the ans of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192020/display-blob-image-through-jsp

Comment: @kiranlanke try this http://fdegrelle.over-blog.com/article-992927.html  check this too http://balusc.blogspot.fr/2007/04/imageservlet.html