# How can I display BLOB in mysql using JSP?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Before display, i have inserted BLOB to MYSQL and success. I used this code to display BLOB to JSP.

```
        Connection con = Koneksi.getKoneksi();
        String id = request.getParameter("id_pengurus");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select foto from pengurus where idpengurus = ?");
        ps.setString(1, id);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        Blob b = rs.getBlob("foto");
        response.setContentType("image/jpg");
        response.setContentLength((int) b.length());
        InputStream is = b.getBinaryStream();
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        byte buf[] = new byte[(int) b.length()];
        is.read(buf);
        os.write(buf);
        os.close();
```

When I use this code to display BLOB in SQL to JSP, it was worked.
When I use this code to display BLOB in MYSQL to JSP, it didn't work. What solution should i do? Sorry for my bad English. Thanks before.

Comment: I don't understand the question but you shouldn't be closing the stream you haven't opened (nothing to do with the problem and more of a general rule).

Comment: sorry before sir. I used that code in JSP to display BLOB in ORACLE SQL. Is it possible that code for display blob SQL and mysql different? Thanks

Comment: You never check how many bytes were read when you called `is.read(buf)`, so you may not have received everything. If you're going to just get the entire BLOB as a byte array, your should just call `byte[] buf = rs.getBytes("foto")` and forget about the `Blob` class.

Comment: I have solved my problem sir Andreas. Just change Blob IMPORT from SQL to MYSQL and it can display image now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Blob` is binary content and `JSP` is `text/html`. Which means you can not combine them, however if you are asking about how to serve the image using `JSP/Servlet` then you can do it by writing it's content to the output stream of the `response`, make sure to set proper headers `Content-Type: image/png` or something like that in the response.

You can have two JSP files. One for serving image content and other to display it.

In the second JSP a simple `<img>` tag would do the trick.

```
<img src="/imagejsp.jsp"/>
```

This would display the image.

Comment: Thank you sir11thdimension for your answer. How to change from binary to byte sir? i have tried in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192020/display-blob-image-through-jsp, but i can't understand sir. Sorry before. Thanks

Comment: I have solved my problem sir. Just change Blob IMPORT from SQL to MYSQL and it can display image now. Thanks a lot for your advice!