# How to play audio that was load from database?

Tags: database, jsf, audio

I develop music site.

On `jsf` page I have HTML `audio` tag
If audio file located in parent of `WEB-INF` for example

`WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF`
  `-- some.mp3`
I just write next piece of code:

```html
<audio ...>
  <source src="#{request.contextPath}/some.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

And after adding controls I could play/pause this audio.

But what should I do if my audio file does not store locally in `WebContent` folder?
I know that audio files should store in DB like BLOB.
After downloading selected audio from DB how should I represent it?(`String` array, some kind of `Stream`?)

In all examples that I saw in the Web peoples play local audio files.
**So, how to play audio (on jsf page) that store in database???**

I hope you understand that I want.

Comment: This has been answered several times in different flavors, but all boils down to creating a servlet like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/how-to-retrieve-and-display-images-from-a-database-in-a-jsp-page or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java Which one do you accept as dupe?

Comment: @BalusC  
I think first one will be better in my case..
But I have several questions about how it works..
First of all, I will have static folder called `audio` in parent of `WEB-INF` 
and `source` tag will looks like `<source src="#{request.contextPath}/audio/#{myBean.audioTitle}" type="audio/mpeg" />`....
Secondly, code above will ask AudioServlet to download audio from database, translate it into `Stream` and set it like `OutputStream` in `response`???

Answer (score 1):

You can not read a file directly from the database : you have to *serve* it to the client.

It works with files inside the `WebContent` folder because those files are served automatically by the web server.

To serve file stored inside the database you'll need to write a `FileServlet`.  Basically this file servlet will:

- respond to a specific request;
- retrieve the file from the database;
- output the file content to the user with a stream.

Have a look at [this](http://balusc.blogspot.ca/2007/07/fileservlet.html) for a good start on FileServlet.