# Spring MVC not resolving image path stored outside webroot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am uploading images and videos and creating respective tags for video and audio to display on view page but somehow image and video path are not getting resolved.

Here is my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contentUpload", headers = "content-type=multipart/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String uploadImage(@RequestParam("fileData") MultipartFile multipartFile, HttpServletRequest request )
{
    String jsonResponse = null;
    boolean isImage = false;
    boolean isVideo = false;
    try
    {
        String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        File directory = null;
        if (multipartFile.getContentType().contains("image"))
        {
            directory = new File(path + "/uploads/images/");
            isImage = true;
        }
        else
        {
            directory = new File(path + "/uploads/videos/");
            isVideo = true;
        }

        byte[] bytes = null;
        File file = null;
        bytes = multipartFile.getBytes();

        if (!directory.exists()) directory.mkdirs();

        file = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath() + System.getProperty("file.separator") + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        stream.write(bytes);
        stream.close();

        if (isImage)
            jsonResponse = "<br /><img src=\"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\" />";
        else if (isVideo)
            jsonResponse = "<video>" + "<source src=\"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\" type=\"" + multipartFile.getContentType() + "\">" + "</video>";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }       
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

I have tried  resources settings in dispatcher.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/uploads/**" location="/#{servletContext.contextPath}/uploads/" />
```

uploaded image path.

```
/home/govi/demo/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/projectImg/uploads/images/batman.jpg
```

please suggest me the changes required.

Comment: Don't, ever, try to store anything under the webapp directory. This directory will, BTW, not exist at all if you deploy a war file. Uploaded images are data. They're not part of the application. They belong to the database or to a data directory outside of the application. You don't want all those data to be lost forever as soon as you redeploy the application.

Comment: so where should I store the content? please provide me some example if possible. I am new to web development.

Comment: Create an empty, dedicated, directory for the images on your file system, and store the images there. `/home/govi/uploaded-images` for example.

Comment: Just like JB Nizet suggested, depending on your scenarios, if many videos and images rather than saving on a data folder and have it saved on the server, I would consider using a Storage Service and save there the data and access it from your web, many benefits to this last approach.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/how-to-retrieve-and-display-images-from-a-database-in-a-jsp-page

Comment: so, File directory = new File("/home/govi/uploads/images/"); right?

Comment: its not working 404 resource not found.

Comment: Yes, because you haven't read the answer I linked to, and thus haven't created the servlet needed to display images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'///' triple slash solved my issue. Now my resource mapping is like this.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/uploads/**" location="file:///home/govi/uploads/" />
```

Anyone facing this issue please go through JB Nizet's comments and also go through this link  [How to retrieve and display images from a database in a JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/how-to-retrieve-and-display-images-from-a-database-in-a-jsp-page)

Answer (score 1):

Use below code line, it may helps you.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/uploads/**"  location="/WEB-INF/projectImg/uploads/" />
```