# How to display image on Jsp page from database using Hibernate and spring MVC

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I am able to find all the data through this code

```
while(it.hasNext())
        {
        Object objnew=it.next();
        PartnerRegistrationIndividual PartRegIndv =(PartnerRegistrationIndividual) objnew;

        pid=PartRegIndv.getId();
        firstname=PartRegIndv.getFname();
        lastname=PartRegIndv.getLname();
        email=PartRegIndv.getEmail();
        mobile=PartRegIndv.getMobile();
        foe=PartRegIndv.getSpeciality();
        expSalPerDay =PartRegIndv.getExpectedSalaryPerDay();
        expSalPerMonth=PartRegIndv.getExpectedSalaryPerMonth();
        current_status=PartRegIndv.getApproval_status();
```

I am using following code to get the data from database...but my webpage goes blank and i get some exception in console..

```
        Blob imgdata=PartRegIndv.getImage();
        imgdata.getBinaryStream();
        OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.getOutputStream().close();
```

Exception which comes in my console...

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet emen threw exception
```

java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:342)
    at org.apache.jsp.allpartners_jsp._jspService(allpartners_jsp.java:318)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:292)

Comment: please provide *Exception which comes in my console...*

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Comment: @TAsk Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

The `response.setContentType()` shouldn't be called after response has already started to be written back to the caller.

Try to invoke `setContentType` before you invoke `getOutputStream`.

If that doesn't help, could you check in your code where `response` or `response.getOuputStream` might be getting called? That way you will know what piece of code started writing back to the browser.

**UPDATE**

Once you start writing to the response. You are now allowed to render a JSP.
If this was a servlet code, you could just "return" without having to forward to a JSP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78338/discussion-between-abhishek-shandilya-and-mecon).

Comment: Images can't be returned in that manner.  In the JSP page, create an HTML IMG element, and make the "src" attribute of that element invoke a URL which will fetch the Image from the server. So, you will need a special Controller method just to retrieve Image.

Comment: <img src="?"  class="img-circle" width="150" >........................I have this one how to put src of that image fetched from database

Comment: JSP can have image tag like this:
<img src="/myapplication/partreg/getImage?id=<%= var.getId() %>" height="200" width="200">

Comment: One simple question is that....how can i show an image on web  page. which is "Blob" type.

Comment: You have to implement a method that accepts URL like I have in my example. 

And in that method, you can execute the same code you had that wrote image data into `response.getOutputStream()`

Comment: ok...got that..can write that method on same page (jsp page).

Comment: In your URL...can you tell me..what do the myapplication   partreg and getImage represent?

Comment: they are dummy pace holders. You would need put a URL that makes sense for your application.

Comment: when i put the "output.write(bdata);" it shows the single image on the same page but also throws the  Exception "getOutputStream() has already been called for this response"

Comment: are you still forwarding the request to a JSP?  When you write such binary data to response.outputStream, then you really Can't (and Should not need to)  forward to a JSP.   JSP is meant for rendering data in HTML page. But what you what is to output binary data to the Browser.

Comment: can you send me some link where i could understand these things or i could able to show images on jsp page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/how-to-retrieve-and-display-images-from-a-database-in-a-jsp-page/2341322#2341322

Comment: any luck with the example?

Comment: i would like to show you ...whole code once which i tried?? may be you can help me there

Answer (score 0):

```
OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();  

response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
```

As you can see, you are fetching response first and setting it's type later, which might be causing the issue.

Try correcting this & if things are still nasty, post stacktrace also.

Comment: Right, looks like I haven't refreshed page after opening question.