# How to view more than one image in a JSP page from database?

Tags: java, image, jsp, struts2

I have problem trying to fetch images from db and then showing them in a JSP page:

**`ImageAction`:**

```java
public class ImageAction {

private  byte[] itemImage;

public byte[] getItemImage() {
    return itemImage;
}

public void setItemImage(byte[] itemImage) {
    this.itemImage = itemImage;
}

public  void  execute() throws Exception{
      try {
          HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
          response.reset();
          response.setContentType("multipart/form-data"); 
          byte[] imgData =(byte[])ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession()
                           .getAttribute("imageData"); 
          System.out.println("imgData :: "+imgData);
          itemImage = imgData;
          ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession().removeAttribute("imageData") ; 
          OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
          out.write(itemImage);
          out.flush();
          out.close();

      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("error :: ");
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
   //   return "success";
  }
}
```

**JSP:**

```jsp
<tr >
    <td> <%= map.get(mapKey) %> </td>
    <td colspan="1" >
        <img src="<s:url value="ImageAction" />" width="115" border="0" />
    </td>   
</tr>
```

Comment: You would need some mechanism on your JSP page to convert your `byte[]` data to image

Comment: Use `stream` result.

Comment: As the answers posted so far are rather hacky and scary, here's an elaborate explanation of the plain JSP/Servlet way, fully independent from Struts or whatever MVC framework you're using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/how-to-retrieve-and-display-images-from-a-database-in-a-jsp-page

Answer (score 1):

What you'll receive on your JSP page would be raw `byte[]`, you need to process it a little, check following:

```
<a src="" id="imageSrc"/>
```

A simple `anchor` tag to display image.

Following code would convert the raw `byte[]` to it's equivalent Base64 string, viz is essential to display image.

```
<%
   byte data[]=request.getParameter(itemImage); //let itemImage for instance hold your data
   String encodedData=Base64.encodeBytes(data);
%>
```

Now you need a little utility on your JSP page to set base64 data

```
<script>
function imageBaseSixtyFourProcessor(baseSixtyFour){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src='';
        var imageUrl='data:image/gif;base64,'+baseSixtyFour;
        $('#imageSrc').attr('src',imageUrl);
        img.src = imageUrl;
    }
}
</script>
```

Call above function:

```
<script>
  imageBaseSixtyFourProcessor(<%encodedData%>);
</script>
```

**Note :** In my case I am displaying `GIF` file, you can change it as per your requirements.

Similarly you can have multiple images displayed in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious usage is to move the image data to some collection, i.e. `Map`. The action should be aware of `mapKey` used to retrieve the image data from the map.

```jsp
<s:iterator value="#session.imageDataMap">
  <img src="<s:url value="ImageAction"><s:param name="mapKey" value="%{key}"/></s:url>" width="115" border="0" /> 
</s:iterator>
```

If you get the data from session, then you should modify the code to use a collection.

```java
...
Map<String, byte[]> imgDataMap =(Map<String, byte[]>)ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get("imageDataMap"); 
imageData = imgDataMap.get(mapKey);
System.out.println("imgData :: "+new Base64Encoder.encode(imgData));
itemImage = imgData;
...
```

In the above example the Struts 2 session map is used instead of servlet session.