# i want to fetch the session attribute from servlet and display it as a image source

Tags: image, jsp, servlets

what i am trying to do is fetching the session attribute from servlet, This attribute contains the path of my desired image which i want to display on jsp page. if i put this attribute like

```
<%=session.getAttribute("imageurl")%>
```

it give me perfect path. but when i do

```
<%String img=(String)session.getAttribute("imageurl");%>
<img src="img" alt=""  width="100" height="100"/>
```

it shows nothing...
please help regarding this scenario

this is my code from servlet

```
 String name=rs.getString("name");
    String image=rs.getString("ppicture");
    String loc = "G:/Friendbook/pictures/";
    String imageurl=loc+image;imageurl=imageurl.trim();
    HttpSession session=req.getSession(); 
    session.setAttribute("name",name);
    session.setAttribute("imageurl",imageurl);
    req.setAttribute("imageurl", imageurl);
    req.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp").forward(req, res);
```

Comment: Hint: what does the source of the generated page look like?

Comment: @MattJacob sir, its just simple jsp page where i need to display the image as a profile picture.. i store the image on particular  location and stored its name in database. then concat both and add it in session.. that session object is "imgurl" in my code.

Comment: I'm telling you to look at the source of the generated page. It's going to show `src="img"` because you haven't interpolated the variable into the template.

Answer (score 1):

In your case src="img" will take soruce as "img".You can use Expression Language in jsp page as follow

```
<img src=${sessionScope.imageurl} alt=""  width="100" height="100"/>
```

Comment: it wont work and i already  interpolated the variable into the template

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh no, you didn't. The additional problem is that you're trying to use a file path instead of an http URL. You can't do that. Look at the generated HTML. It will contain something like `<img src="G:/Friendbook/pictures/foo.png" />`. Assuming this was accepted by the browser (and it isn't): how can you know that the visitor of your web app is using windows, and has a G: drive containing these directories and files? Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/how-to-retrieve-and-display-images-from-a-database-in-a-jsp-page

Comment: Your image path should contain http URL , otherwise it wont work.

Comment: @JBNizet  Thanks a lot for your valuable guideline.

Comment: i change my uploadServlet  and set the location into my workspace inside WebContent  and now both upload and download working properly...

Answer (score 1):

Error in img tag:

Do something like this, may it help:

```
<img src=<%= img %> alt=""  width="100" height="100"/>
```