# How to display list of image from database using jsp Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

As I am using Image datatype in sql database. I am able to display one image using jsp servlet. However, what if I want to retrieve list of images to be display using servlet?

here is my single image display method:

```
    byte barray[]  = photo.getImage();
    response.setContentType("image/jpg");
    response.setContentLength(barray.length);
    response.getOutputStream().write(photo.getImage());
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    response.getOutputStream().close();
```

JSP :

```
<img src=" ${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath }/getPhotoServlet " ></img>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve and display images from a database in a JSP page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/how-to-retrieve-and-display-images-from-a-database-in-a-jsp-page)