# tomcat 8 access image that is located on webapps using tomcat url

Tags: java, tomcat

I have one java rest web service that is deployed on Tomcat 8 Server, this Tomcat 8 is installed on Ubuntu Server.

My java rest web service work is that it save images into the below location

```
/opt/tomcat/webapps/TestWebService/WEB-INF/image/xyz.image
```

Images are successfully save on above location

But i want to access these images via url like

`http://192.168.1.185:8080/TestWebService/WEB-INF/image/xyz.image`

So how can i do this?

I am using Tomcat 8 and Java.

Comment: You write a servlet that reads the data as a bytestream. You simply use the servlet URL in a html img element. Similar to [this answer that reads the img data from database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2341322/744133).

Comment: Another way is to modify the `server.xml` as [exemplified in another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1812356/744133) to include the path of your images within the context of your webapp.

Comment: Don't expose the contents of your WEB-INF folder. Place the images in a resources folder, or some other folder within your web application itself.

Answer (score 1):

The specification of Java Web Containers doesn't allow implementors to serve files inside of `WEB-INF` folder. If you want Tomcat to serve the image content, put the files outside `WEB-INF` folder.

```
/opt/tomcat/webapps/TestWebService/image/xyz.image
```

You can access it via

```
http://192.168.1.185:8080/TestWebService/image/xyz.image
```

Comment: I change my code and image is created on "/opt/tomcat/webapps/TestWebService/images/20160718195340.png" successfully but when i access "http://192.168.1.185:8080/TestWebService/images/20160718195340.png" page is blank.