# How to print arraylist of blob/images in a JSP file from MySQL DB

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jsp, printing

Good day! Currently, I have a page in my web application that aims to print an allocation file. This is currently how I want it to be:

1. Print the list of allocated people by using a datatable.
2. Print images of resumes per person by having storing the blob/images in an ArrayList.

I can already do step 1. This is the following JS code that im using:

```
    <script>
    function printContent(el){
    var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
    var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;

    document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
    }
    </script>
```

This code gets the data-target of the modal i am using to get the datatable containing the names of the allocated people. I do not want to make the printing of resumes and the datatable because I think that it is harder to implement. I want to make it two functions that will use the same query from my DB (1.select allocated names 2.select blob/image files) because I think that would be easier for me to do.

However, I do not know how I can print the ArrayList of resumes (img/blob) or where I can start. Any leads on how I can do this? I would also prefer if i will use Java in doing this task because I do not know a thing or two about PHP. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I do not want to show the images in my page because it will take up too much space, in my system, it is understood that every person allocated has his own resume in the form of an image. I just want to save the arraylist of the images then print it.

EDIT 2: What I mean by print is printing using a printer, not print as to display in the computer screen.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/how-to-retrieve-and-display-images-from-a-database-in-a-jsp-page) could help you get in the right direction.

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry for any misunderstanding