# Display all images from Database (blob) on a jsp file in a table

Tags: java, css, mysql, jsp

i need your help. I want to display all the images from my database (there are 6 images in there) on a jsp file. Why JSP File and not using outputreader? -> Cause i want to style the table with css in the next step so i have to do this on this special way.

Select all the pictures of the database:

```
public static List<Picture> displayPicture() {

List<Picture> list = new ArrayList<Picture>();

try {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:9999/xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM PICTURES";

    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {

         byte[] imageData = rs.getBytes("File_Data");
         String imageFileName = rs.getString("File_Name");

         Picture picture = new Picture();
         picture.setImageData(imageData);
         picture.setImageFileName(imageFileName);
         list.add(picture);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return list;
```

Now i want to save this List in setAttribute to send it to the JSP-File:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
List<Picture> list =null;
list = DBUtils.displayPicture();

request.setAttribute("pictureList", list);

RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/pictureView.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

And finally the JSP-File:

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${pictureList}" var="picture">
    <tr>
        <td>${picture.imageData}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

So i want to display all the images in a table. At the moment it doesnt matter how the table looks like. With this code i get only a table with special numbers and letters. I think its the binary code, right? (For example: beans.Picture@22debaab or [B@3f391312])

Now where is the mistake? in the Code of the JSP-File cause i have to use

```
<img src="">
```

or something else? If this was the mistake, how should be coding this?

Thank you guys

Dear Newbie

Comment: Can you convert your image data into `base64` format?

Comment: This could help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/how-to-retrieve-and-display-images-from-a-database-in-a-jsp-page

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna   I tried already with base64 but i didnt worked. How would you solve it, if you do it with base64?

Comment: @JoseLuis that looks really great! Thank u i try it

Comment: @newbieQwer Please show the code, what you have tried with base64 ?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna 
`List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

...

while (rs.next()) {
     byte[] imageData = rs.getBytes("File_Data");
     list.add(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageData));
}` And then i tried this in JSP in the `td` `img src="data:image/jpg;base64,${picture}"`

Comment: Please use `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` and let me know what happens. use the method `Base64.encodeBase64String()` to encode base64 string.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code snippet in controller side.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rs.next()) { 
    byte[] imageData = rs.getBytes("File_Data"); 
    list.add(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(imageData)); 
}
request.setAttribute("pictureList", list);
```

And show it in html page like that,

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${pictureList}" var="picture">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,${picture}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```