# Displayimage saved as blob in mysql to the view in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a problem to display a product image stored in the MySQL database as a blob datatype. There are few other things that stored in the product table such as (id,pname,quantity,price,photo). I don't have any problem to show the (id,pname,quantity,price) value from the product table in the jsp except the value from **photo** column. Below is the code that I use:

ProductDAO.java

```
public List<Product> getAllProduct() {
        List<Product> productlist = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Product p = new Product();
                p.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                p.setPname(rs.getString("pname"));
                p.setQuantity(rs.getInt("quantity"));
                p.setPrice(rs.getDouble("price"));
                p.setPhoto(rs.getBlob("photo"));
                productlist.add(p);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
        return productlist;
    }
```

view.jsp

```
<div class="row">
 <%
   ProductDAO dao = new ProductDAO();
   List<Product> productList = dao.getAllProduct();
   DecimalFormat priceFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

   for (Product p: productList) {
 %>
  <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/<%= p.getPhoto()%>" width="200" height="200">
  <a><%= p.getPname()%></a>
  <span class="item_price">RM<%= priceFormatter.format(p.getPrice())%></span>
</div>
<%
  }
%>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve and display images from a database in a JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/how-to-retrieve-and-display-images-from-a-database-in-a-jsp-page)

Comment: I have tried to follow that suggestion @PetrAleksandrov but I didn't manage to get it.

Comment: The following answer explains the issue and solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2341322/5990117